# Char array gives error when initializing

Tags: c++

It can be simple but I m new about c++
In char arrays we can let the compiler to count number of characters in the string like

```
char myarray[]="stringvar";
```

its ok, but if i change the code as below,the compiler gives error

```
string myvar = "stringvar";
char myarray[] =myvar;

error: initializer fails to determine size of myarray
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
string myvar = "stringvar";
const char * myarray = myvar.c_str(); //immutable string
```

In this case, the data which`myarray` points to, lives as long as the lifetime of `myvar`.

However, if you want a *mutable* string or, a string which may last longer (or shorter) than the lifetime of `myvar`, then you've to allocate memory yourself as:

```
char * myarray = new char[myvar.size()+1]; //mutable string
std::strcpy(myarray, myvar.c_str());

//you've to deallocate the memory yourself as:
delete [] myarray;
```

Comment: so in first decleration char myarray[]="stringvar"; compiler understand "stringvar" as pointer? not string class ? am I right?

Comment: @mekici: Yes, that is not string-class. Also, the type of `"stringvar"` is not pointer either. It is an array of type `char[10]` which may convert into `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign an `std::string` object to initialize and create a character array.

You will need to copy the `std::string` in to the array.

```
strcpy(myarray,myvar.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string myvar = "stringvar"
char* myarray = (char*)myvar.c_str();
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

There is error, because `char myarray[]` is equivalent to `char* myarray`. It is just a pointer to char. So you need a compatible initializer there (like `char*` or `const char*`). But you are trying to pass an instance of `string` class, that is not a pointer.

If you wish to assign myarray to a string (make it point to the same location) you may do this

```
char myarray[] = const_cast<char[]> myvar.c_str();
```

But in any case, its not good idea, until you definitely know what you're doing.