# How to insert variables values in the registry with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, variables, registry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Char array gives error when initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149950/char-array-gives-error-when-initializing)

I want to insert an environment variable in the windows registry, so i tied the following C++ code :

```
string appDataPath = getenv("appdata");

    HKEY hkey;
    char value[] = appDataPath.c_str();

    RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Currentversion\\Run", 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &hkey);
    RegSetValueEx (hkey, "MyProgram", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE) value, strlen(value) + 1);
    RegCloseKey(hkey);
```

The codeblock debug output tell me : `error: initializer fails to determine size of 'value'`
I think it's because the compilator need to know the size of my variable before compiling, however i don't know how to fix that...

Thanks !

Comment: Arrays are not pointers? (recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
const char * value = appDataPath.c_str();
```

(Read the < string > reference to find the return type of `c_str()`, it will tell you that it is indeed `const char *`.)

---

Regarding your question of how to concatenate two strings:

Do that with C++ strings rather than with `char *`s and convert them later:

```
string newstring = appDataPath;
newstring.append("some text");
const char * value = newstring.c_str();
```

Comment: Thanks you, it is working successfully !

Comment: Do you know how can i do something like that :
const char * value = appDataPath.c_str()+"some text";
thanks

Answer (score 1):

`c_str()` returns a `const char*`, not a `char[]`.  Change

```
char value[] = appDataPath.c_str();
```

to

```
const char* value = appDataPath.c_str();
```

The compiler is giving the error because an array variable requires a length - which is not being provided.

Comment: so value is an array of char pointers?

Comment: @user93353 - nope that should `const char* value` not `const char* vallue[]`.  Edited the answer